# How to clear IPython session?

Tags: python, memory, ipython, cls

There's just a lot of code in IPython session which I can access using up and down arrow on the keyboard. I mean it does clear the screen using some phrases, although I'm still able to access the previous codes which means it's storing them somewhere. How to **completely** clear the session?

*I tried:*

- `cls`
- `%cls`
- `!cls`
- `get_ipython().run_line_magic('cls', '')`
- `%reset -f` (this one does del all variables but I still can see previous code using up and down arrows on the keyboard)